# How to sort NameValueCollection using a key in C#?

Tags: c#, sorting, collections

I've written following code and it works too - but I wanted to know whether their is better way than this :

```
 NameValueCollection optionInfoList = ..... ;
 if (aSorting)
            {
                optionInfoListSorted = new nameValueCollection();        
                String[] sortedKeys = optionInfoList.AllKeys; 
                Array.Sort(sortedKeys);
                foreach (String key in sortedKeys)
                    optionInfoListSorted.Add(key, optionInfoList[key]);

                return optionInfoListSorted;
            }
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a [SortedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx) instead.

Comment: SortedList and SortedDictionary don't allow duplicate keys, which may force some to use NameValueCollection.

Comment: If a `NameValueCollection` is used, and sorted as described in the example with duplicate keys, the order is indeterminate for duplicate keys, so the list really isn't sorted, is it?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you could use a different kind of list, that supports sorting directly?

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> optionInfoList = ...;
if (sorting) {
   optionInfoList.Sort((x,y) => String.Compare(x.Key, y.Key));
}
return optionInfoList;
```

Comment: I need to pass this to another class and having List<KeyValuePair> in my method signatures gives me Code Analysis errors.

Comment: Would you be specific by what you mean by "Code Analysis Errors"?

Answer (score 1):

If you *have* to use `NameValueCollection` and you don't have many items in the collection, then it's fine.  No need to get any fancier than that if it get's the job done.

If it's a performance bottleneck, then revisit.

Answer (score 0):

I made this fiddle because I needed to sort querystring values in order to properly compare URIs: (H/T to [Jacob](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28204663/509770))

https://dotnetfiddle.net/eEhkNk

This preserves duplicate keys:

```
public static string[] QueryStringOmissions = new string[] { "b" };

public static NameValueCollection SortAndRemove(NameValueCollection collection)
{
    var orderedKeys = collection.Cast<string>().Where(k => k != null).OrderBy(k => k);
    var newCollection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(String.Empty);
    foreach(var key in orderedKeys)
    {
        if (!QueryStringOmissions.Contains(key))
        {
            foreach(var val in collection.GetValues(key).Select(x => x).OrderBy(x => x).ToArray())
            {
                newCollection.Add(key, val);
            }
        }
    }
    return newCollection;
}
```