# How to Sort NameValue Collection and Store it in a string

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, c#-4.0

Here I am storing two set of querystring parameters into two different namevalue collection. The querystring parameter order may vary so I just want to sort the order and then I need to store namevalue collection to a string.

**Updated Code :**

```
string url1 = @"http://www.somewebsitesampletest.com/dcs7o?data=142248494&dcp=smre&nparam=4567P&email=xxx.com";

string url2 = @"http://www.somewebsitesampletest.com/dcs7o?dcp=smre&data=142248494&email=xxx.com&nparam=4567P";

var NameValueCollection1 = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(url1);
var NameValueCollection2 = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(url2);
```

**ExpectedResult:**
After Sorting and converting to string the result should look like the below one

```
string query1 = "data=142248494&dcp=smre&email=xxx.com&nparam=4567P";
string query2 = "data=142248494&dcp=smre&email=xxx.com&nparam=4567P";
```

Comment: It would be better if you showed us what you have actually tried.

Comment: I think ?& is wrong format of the url. Also you want sort but in you expected result you show nparam before email, what kind of sorting is this ?

Comment: why are you even putting it into a NVC in the first place? seems like all you want to do is capture the query portion of the URI, right? so just substring everything after the "?", that's faster and more elegant. Parsing everything out to a NVC only to reconstitute it into a string again is counterintuitive in so many ways.

Comment: I am using NVC for comparison purpose. This is how I am comparing, 
public bool CompareNameValueCollections(NameValueCollection exp, NameValueCollection rec)
        {
            return exp.AllKeys.OrderBy(key => key)
                   .SequenceEqual(rec.AllKeys.OrderBy(key => key))
                   && exp.AllKeys.All(key => exp[key] == rec[key]);
        }

after comparison I am displaying to the user that what are all the params I have compared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using Linq.

Basically it changes the `NameValueCollection` to an `IEnumerable` of the keys using `Cast<T>`, then the rest is fairly self explanatory.

```
public string GetSortedQueryString(string url)
{
    var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(url);

    // Ignore null keys (caused by your ?& at the start of the query string
    var orderedKeys = queryString.Cast<string>().Where(k => k != null).OrderBy(k => k);

    return string.Join("&", orderedKeys.Select(k => string.Format("{0}={1}", k, queryString[k])));
}
```

Results for your URLs would be:

```
data=142248494&dcp=smre&email=xxx.com&nparam=4567P
data=142248494&dcp=smre&email=xxx.com&nparam=4567P
```

Email comes before nparam, unlike your expected solution (I'm assuming that was a mistake).

Answer (score 1):

use **LINQ** with a `Dictionary` and a `list` of `KeyValuePair` :

```
string url1 = @"http://www.somewebsitesampletest.com/dcs7o?&data=142248494&dcp=smre&nparam=4567P&email=xxx.com";
string query1 ="";
Dictionary<String, String> paramDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

var query = from match in urlString.Split('?').Where(m => m.Contains('='))
                .SelectMany(pr => pr.Split('&'))
            where match.Contains('=')
            select new KeyValuePair<string, String>(
                match.Split('=')[0],
                match.Split('=')[1]);

query.ToList().ForEach(kvp => paramDict.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value));

var List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> paramList = paramDict.ToList();

paramList.Sort();

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> pair in list)
{
    query1+=pair.Key+"="+pair.Value+"&";
}
query1=query1.TrimEnd('&');
```

Answer (score 0):

I made this fiddle because I needed to sort querystring values in order to properly compare URIs: (H/T to Jacob's answer)

https://dotnetfiddle.net/eEhkNk

This preserves duplicate keys:

```
public static string[] QueryStringOmissions = new string[] { "b" };

public static NameValueCollection SortAndRemove(NameValueCollection collection)
{
    var orderedKeys = collection.Cast<string>().Where(k => k != null).OrderBy(k => k);
    var newCollection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(String.Empty);
    foreach(var key in orderedKeys)
    {
        if (!QueryStringOmissions.Contains(key))
        {
            foreach(var val in collection.GetValues(key).Select(x => x).OrderBy(x => x).ToArray())
            {
                newCollection.Add(key, val);
            }
        }
    }
    return newCollection;
}
```